# I have a problem using AutoFilter in vba. Getting error -2147417848 (80010108)

Tags: excel, vba, button, runtime-error, autofilter

I don´t know why i´m getting this error:

```
Run-time Error -2147417848 (80010108)
Automation Error
The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

i´m just trying to run this short code in a Commandbutton to find out how AutoFilter works.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Test").Activate

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

ActiveSheet.Range("A5:B6").AutoFilter field:=2

End Sub
```

I think maybe the problem is not having some features in excel.

How can i discard this?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, your code, even if it does almost nothing, should not raise an error on most computers. On mine, for instance, it runs without any error.

But, when VBA do not understand what is to be done, may raise such an error...

So, do you have any values in that short range, especially in column B5:B6?

If yes, try putting at list a Criteria condition in your filter. If criteria will be a real one, it will be better:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:B6").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="=0", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Does it work in this way?

Comment: I've tried by aggregating the same criteria and some values but the error still appearing.